# How to read log messages for CombineFn function in GCP Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am creating an Apache Beam streaming processing pipeline to run in GCP Dataflow. I have a number of transforms that extends DoFn and CombineFn. In DoFn logs are visualised fine using the LOGS window in the Dataflow job details. However, the logs from CombineFn transforms are not shown.

I tried different log levels and they also show fine using the DirectRunner.

Here is some sample code. I changed the input and output to String for brevity, there are some custom classes in my code.

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.avro.reflect.Nullable;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.DefaultCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Combine.CombineFn;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class AverageSpv extends CombineFn<String, AverageSpv.Accum, String> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AverageSpv.class);

    @DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
    public static class Accum implements Serializable {
        @Nullable String id;
    }

    @Override
    public Accum createAccumulator() {
        return new Accum();
    }

    @Override
    public Accum addInput(Accum accumulator, String input) {
        LOG.info("Add input: id {}, input);

        accumulator.id = input;

        return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public Accum mergeAccumulators(Iterable<Accum> accumulators) {
        LOG.info("Merging accumulator");

        Accum merged = createAccumulator();
        for (Accum accumulator : accumulators) {
            merged.id = accumulator.id;            
        }

        return merged;
    }

    @Override
    public VehicleSpeedPerSegmentInfo extractOutput(Accum accumulator) {
        LOG.info("Extracting accumulator");

        LOG.info("Extract output: id {}", acummulator.id);

        return acummulator.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did a repro and the same happens to me with the Cloud Console. However, I can see them fine in Stackdriver Logging. Adding [some notes](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/cf163038ce432d21b20920aa419e1123) in case it helps.

Comment: Ok, when I click the CombineFn step in the Dataflow console and then click LOGS there is nothing there like you also found out. When I click the StackDriver link, the log is still not showing in StackDriver. However, when I deselect the CombineFn step and the go to the general LOGS and then StackDriver, the CombineFn logs are there. Thanks for the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Beam CombineFn operations are executed across several steps in Dataflow. (Specifically, as much pre-combining happens before shuffling all results to a single key, and then all the upstream results are merged together into a final result in a subsequent post-GBK step.) The fact that there's no single execution "step" corresponding to the original Combine step in the graph is probably what's preventing the logs from being found.

This is a bug and should be fixed. As mentioned, a workaround is to look at all logs from the pipeline.